# AngularJS Double HTTP requests, is this a good solution or am i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

**The Structure**

I have two controllers and one model.

1. a order controller which handles one step of the order process
2. a order nav controller which handles only the navigation of the order
3. a order model which handles all data of the order.

All information is stored in the order object, depending on which bundle you choose you receive a tab ment to configure that bundle.

While navigating through different steps of the order the nav controller is always there doing its job and the order controller could change in different controllers necessary for the certain configure step your currently at.

**The scenario**

When loading the first state the order controller is initializing and the nav controller is initializing. Both calling the "OrderModel.getOrder()" method, which is a promise with a http call.

If both controller are initializing and the promise is not resolved yet it causes double request to the api, which i think is a little bit overkill.

**The solution**

I created a wrapper around the $q library, which adds a new method, unique.

The unique method is storing the promise into the model, if the promise does not exists yet it creates a new promise, else it returns the promise which is not resolved yet. This prevents multiple http calls.

**The question**

Because this solution looks so easy and straightforward i feel like i am doing something wrong, what do you guys think about this structure / solution?

**Example code:**

Controllers getOrder method:

```
/**
     * @name getOrders
     * @param force
     * @description
     * Get the given order
     */
    function getOrder (id, force) {
        return $q(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                Orders.getOrder(id, force).then(
                    function (order) {
                        vm.order = order;
                        resolve(order);
                    },
                    reject
                );
            }
        );
    }
```

Model getOrder method:

```
function getOrder (id, force) {
        var url = AppConfig.ApiUrl + '/order/' + id;
        var promiseUrl = url + '-force-' + force;

        return $qPromise.unique(promiseUrl, function (resolve, reject) {
            if (!force && model.orders[id]) {
                return resolve(model.orders[id]);
            }

            $http.get(url, { bearer: true }).then(
                function (response) {
                    model.orders[id] = response.data.data;
                    resolve(model.orders[id]);
                },
                reject
            );
        });
    }
```

The $q wrapper
    (function () {

```
angular.module('app').factory('$qPromise', qWrapper);

qWrapper.$inject = ['$q'];

/**
 * @name QWrapper
 * @param $q
 * @returns {*}
 * @description
 * Wrapper arround $q to add the unique method.
 */
function qWrapper($q) {
    var model = {
        promises: {}
    };

    $q.unique = uniquePromise;

    return $q;

    /**
     * @name uniquePromise
     * @param id
     * @param cb
     * @description
     * Promise wrapper for preventing multiple calls for the same data.
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function uniquePromise (id, cb) {
        if (model.promises[id]) {
            return model.promises[id];
        }

        var promise = model.promises[id] = $q(cb);
        promise.catch(console.warn);

        $q.when(
            promise,
            function () { delete model.promises[id];  },
            function () { delete model.promises[id];  }
        );

        return promise;
    }
}

})();
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort to ask this question. But I have a doubt for Why you call `getOrder()` method in both controller?

Comment: Why not just cache the response of `getOrder()` so whichever calls it the second time hits the cache instead of the API?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Because the nav controller needs the order object for depending the navigation, i want to receive the order object from the model and be sure it has it. I call twice getOrder and getOrder makes sure it returns the object if it already has it. If not it will call the http call.

Comment: @Ankh I indeed could use the angular cache, till now i did not use this option yet.

Comment: @Ankh As i mentioned i did not use angular cache before. If i use the cache i think the scenario would be the same? Isnt angular caching the result if the result is given? Which causes still double http requests because we are talking about a difference of ms in which these method is being called?

Comment: An alternative is to call `getOrder` once when the app loads and broadcast the result to all controllers that need it. Each controller just needs to have an `$on` callback for the event to handle the response.

Comment: @Ankh isn't that kind of bad practice?

Comment: Explain how that's bad practice..?

Comment: The services / factories  are actually for sharing data not the scope listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced a scenario where I had to make two http calls at the same time as both http calls gives me their specific json. So I had to do this,

```js
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('contactController',function($scope,$http,$q)
{
 
 var promise1=$http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
 var promise2=$http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){ 
 $scope.first=data[0];
 $scope.second=data[1];
    console.log("------FIRST HTTP RESPONSE_____");
 console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.first));
      console.log("------SECOND HTTP RESPONSE_____");

 console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.second));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="contactController">
  </body>
```

This actually works. $scope.first would give the result of first http call and $scope.second gives result of second http call.

I ain't sure if it serves the purpose you need but I just shared what I knew.Perhaps some clue can help.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This is only a different scenario, you are now speaking about 2 seperate calls on which u want to wait till both are resolved, my question is different.